# Is there a python method to set the specified elements to be some value in a list?

Tags: python

numpy has a function to set the specified elements to be some value

```
a=numpy.zeros(10)
numpy.put(a, [2,3],1)
```

However, this method will directly change 'a' and return None if succeed.

Is there anyway we can keep 'a' intact and return the new array instead?

(I don't have to use numpy, and least dependency will be more preferred)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without a function call, and in my opinion somewhat more readable, you can do this:

```
>>> a = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
>>> b = a[:]
```

```
>>> b[1:3] = [2, 3]
```

```
>>> a
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
>>> b
[0, 2, 3, 0, 0]
```

Note that `a[:]` can be very slow for large lists, because  - as Makato says - it creates a completely new copy of the list. This is also the reason why numpy ships with the "in situ" (in place) function `put()`. If you can, avoid copying the list altogether.

To get a sense of the performance, you can think of `a[:]` as `[i for i in a]`.

I'm not familiar with numpy, so in case I misunderstood and you want to "insert x at positions [a, b, c]", the other way around, instead, you could do this:

```
>>> def put(my_list, x, positions):
...     return [x if n in positions else i for n, i in enumerate(my_list)]
...
>>> put(a, 1, [1, 2])
[0, 1, 1, 0, 0]
```

or, alternatively,

```
>>> b = a[:]
>>> b[1:3] = [1] * 2
>>> b
[0, 1, 1, 0, 0]
```

Which will be slightly slower.

Comment: the put function is exactly what I want. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

None that i know of. You can use this (not so efficient but nice).

```
f = lambda a: lambda b: lambda v: [(v if i in b else a[i]) for i in range(len(a))]
f ([0,0,0,0,0]) ([2,3]) (1)
```

If I wanted something more efficient, I would choose this:

```
def f(a, b, v):
    c = a[:]
    for i in b: c[i] = v
    return c
```

Comment: It should be mentioned that, instead of `(λ a: λ b: λ c: a + b + c)(a)(b)(c)`, you can just write `(λ a, b, c: a + b + c)(a, b, c)`.

Answer (score 0):

You could initialize this way:

```
a = [0]*10
```

And then just make a copy and modify it.

Answer (score 0):

Its not difficult to implement:

```
def put(orig, where, what):
    return map((lambda i:what if i in where else orig[i]), range(len(orig)))
```

Comment: This function will return `[0, [2, 3], [2, 3], 0, 0]`, if `where` is `[1, 2]`. I think the question is asking for `where = 1` returning `[0, 2, 3, 0, 0]` instead.

Comment: ...also. I'd avoid source code that reads `what if i` — it must be up to something!

Comment: @StefanoPalazzo, no, it would return [0,0,1,1,0,0,0...]  try it yourself.

Comment: So it does - sorry about that. I wrote that comment under the impression that the user wanted to do `put(a, 1, [2, 3])`, not `put(a, [2, 3], 1)`.